# ASP.net time rendering differently on different servers

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, timezone, timezone-offset

I have two webservers, WEB1 and WEB2.  The function:

```
public static string ToTimeAgoHTML(this DateTime date)
{
    return "<time class=\"timeago\" datetime=\"" + date.ToString("o") + "\">" + date.FriendlyDate() + "</time>";
}
```

Is called on a value.  These render as:

**WEB1**

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2017-04-03T15:12:04.9072263Z">3 Apr, 2017</time>
```

**WEB2**

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2017-04-03T15:12:04.9072263">3 Apr, 2017</time>
```

Note that Web1 renders with a `z` at the end, whereas Web2 doesn't do this.   This is causing the requests on Web2 to be shown 1 hour in the past.

Both webservers timezones are set the `(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time` in Windows.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: What's the culture?

Comment: @Mason both webservers are the same in IIS `Invariant Language (Invariant Country)`

Comment: I would verify on the actual thread. Check `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`

Comment: @Mason both cultures are `en-US` on both servers

Comment: Culture is irrelevant in this case.  The `"o"` specifier is always aligned to [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which uses the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output when using `ToString("o")` is related to the `Kind` property of the `DateTime` you pass in:

- With `DateTimeKind.Utc`, the string will end with `Z` - which signifies UTC
- With `DateTimeKind.Local`, the string will end with an offset from UTC, such as `-07:00`.
- With `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, the string will just end after the time portion. This could be any point in time, as no time zone offset information is conveyed.

Note that this is exactly aligned with the ISO8601 standard.  It is also described [in the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip).

To figure out why one server is producing different output than the other, you'll have to figure out where they are taking their data from.  My guess is that Web1 is sending a value that originates from `DateTime.UtcNow` and Web2 is reading a value from a file, database, or has it manually constructed without specifying a kind.

Comment: You are correct, thank you!  One of the servers was reading from Redis, where the Kind was unspecified.

Comment: Use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` on retrieval from Redis.